# Load an entire page through AJAX in React/Redux

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux

It's the first time I'm facing this case in React and I'm wondering which direction I should go.

I have two different apps, one in AngularJS (1.x) and another in React/Redux.

The app in Angular(older) is a kind of CMS with different templates.

The one in React is a new app which should give to the users the option to choose different templates.

Basically, what I'm doing is to create through ExpressJS static pages ex: `express.static(__dirname + '/live-pages/')` (for the Angular app) and then using an iframe to load the AngularJS app with different templates.

Now I'm struggling to understand the best way to remove this iframe and use the old fashion AJAX way to append HTML to the page.

First thing to come to my mind to solve that is to create a new property in state model ex: `"template": "<html>...</html>"` and then use the property `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. But it does not seem to be the right thing to do, this page comes with HTML,CSS and Javascript. The content of the page could be very big as well.

How can I replace my iframe in this situation in a React/Redux app ?

Comment: I would say that this isn't an appropriate use of React/Redux, and that you should seek to rewrite the app completely _or_ segregate the two apps deliberately. React and Redux demand (well, strongly prefer) full control over application and DOM state, and what you're suggesting would deny them that. Sounds like more trouble than it's worth!

Comment: rewrite the angular app wouldn't be a option for me. in this case I prefer to use iframes. too much to rewrite.

Comment: then you're better off not transitioning to React. What is it about React that makes this worthwhile? Most things are certainly achievable in Angular (albeit messily, I have found), and that would save you some grief. iframes are fine and React/Redux-friendly, but I'm assuming you want interaction between the two. Getting that to happen is going to be more work than a rewrite, probably regardless of the size of the app you've written.

Comment: the only interaction is to show a live template. through ajax would be amazing the user experience but I have to think about it.